# Doctrine 2 - ManyToOne association not working

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, associations

I need a hand with the following code.
I have this two clases:

```
Class Expert{
    /**
    * @var integer
    *
    * @ORM\Id
    * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
    * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
    */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    protected $username;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    protected $email;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=40)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    protected $password;
}

Class Job{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="titulo", type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    protected $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    protected $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Expert")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="expert_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $assigned_expert;

}
```

And this custom Repository:

```
class JobRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function getTechnicianFinishedJobs($id)
    {
        $Q = $this->getQueryBuilder('j')
                  ->where('j.expert = :expert_id')
                  ->setParameter('expert_id', $id)
                  ->getQuery()
        try{
            return $q->getResult();
        }catch(NoResultException $e){
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this I get the following error:

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 68 near 'expert = :e': Error: Class Job has no field or association named expert
```

The idea is that one expert can be assigned to many jobs and one job can be assigned to one expert . The job needs to know who's the designated expert but not the other way around, so that's why I use a ManyToOne unidirectional association.
I tried changing the repository to ->where('j.expert_id = :expert_id') and other combinations with no avail.

Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If 'j' is your job table, you can't use j.expert, because this is (as far as I can tell) no attribute of your table/entity. You named the field 'expert_id'.
I guess it should be:

```
$Q = $this->getQueryBuilder('j')
                  ->where('j.assigned_expert = :expert_id')
                  ->setParameter('expert_id', $id)
                  ->getQuery()
```

@alvk4: He explained why he didn't use bidirectional association. What you suggested, forgive me if I'm wrong, is bidirectional association.

Comment: @alvk4: Ah ok thanks for correcting that, I'll edit this. But the bidirectional association shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You miss something on your annotation see an working example:

```
/**
 * Fluency\Bundle\DesktopBundle\Entity\Application
 *
 * @ORM\Table(
 *  name="desktop.applications",
 *  uniqueConstraints={
 *      @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="applications_jsid_key", columns={"jsid"}),
 *      @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="applications_type_key", columns={"type"}),
 *      @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="applications_classname_key", columns={"classname"})
 *  }
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Fluency\Bundle\DesktopBundle\Entity\Repository\ApplicationRepository")
 */
class Application
{
...
    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Fluency\Bundle\DesktopBundle\Entity\ApplicationFile", mappedBy="application", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="desktop.application_files",
     *   joinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="idapplication", referencedColumnName="idapplication")
     *   }
     * )
     */
    private $files;
...
}


/**
 * Fluency\Bundle\DesktopBundle\Entity\ApplicationFile
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="desktop.application_files")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class ApplicationFile
{
...
   /**
     * @var \Fluency\Bundle\DesktopBundle\Entity\Application
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Application", inversedBy="files")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="idapplication", referencedColumnName="idapplication", onDelete="CASCADE")
     * })
     */
    private $application;
...
}
```

See a working example of DQL on my repository class:

```
...
    public function getApplicationFilesByJsid($jsid)
    {
        if(empty($jsid) OR !$jsid OR !is_string($jsid))
        {
            throw new \Psr\Log\InvalidArgumentException();
        }

        $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('a, af, m, ft')
            ->from($this->getEntityName(), 'a')
            ->innerJoin('a.files', 'af')
            ->innerJoin('a.module', 'm')
            ->innerJoin('af.filetype', 'ft')
            ->where('a.active = 1 AND a.jsid = :jsid')
            ->setParameter('jsid', $jsid)
            ->orderBy('af.id', 'ASC')
            ->getQuery();

        $applicationFiles = $query->getSingleResult(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);

        return $applicationFiles;
    }
```

...

@enigma: Yes is bidirectional, but your DQL its'n right, would be `j.assigned_expert`, but anyway the Expert is owning side of relationship, also he needs set `mappedBy=assigned_expert` on annotation.

Comment: As I read in the Doctrine documentation ManyToOne unidirectional associations don't need a mappedBy or inversedBy declaration. Here is the example from doctrine site:                                /**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Address")
 * @JoinColumn(name="address_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */                                                                 Also I don't want a field in the user table to be saved for the assiged job, so the job is the owning side. Correct me if I'm wrong please I'm quite new to symfony and doctrine.